# jquery drag and drop with multiple boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

Hello,

I have multiple boxes and each box has list of images. I want to drag image from one box to another box. So it is working for me but when I do drag and drop in a box itself than it is not working.

When I do drag image from div 298 to div 299 it is working. But when I apply drag and drop in 298 box so it is not working. I apply all the possible try but I can't find the exact solution. please help.

**My Javascript Code**:

```
$('.draggable_1,.draggable_2').sortable({
  connectWith: ".droppable",
  receive: function (event, ui) {
    changePanoramaOrder();
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

**My Html**:

```
<div id="298" class="draggable_1 droppable ui-sortable">
  <div class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle" style="background-image: url('upload/579323405bfdf-1024.jpg')"></div>
  <div class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle" style="background-image: url('upload/579323405bfdf-10211.jpg')"></div>
</div>
<div id="299" class="draggable_1 droppable ui-sortable">
     <div class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle" style="background-image: url('upload/579323405bfdf-1025.jpg')"></div>
</div>
```